# How to prove lim $\displaystyle \lim_{|x|\to\infty}e^{-2b|x|}=0$

Tags: calculus, limits

Let $a>1$ and $b>0$.
How to prove
$$ \lim_{|x|\to\infty}e^{-2b|x|}=0$$?

Comment: Since x tends to positive infinity you can only consider the positive values of x i.e $-2b\mid x\mid$ becomes $-2bx$.....

Comment: As usual, the first step is to *try* to prove it. What have you done so far?

Comment: Exponential growth always beats out polynomial growth.

Comment: So essentially, since $b>0$, the exponent of $e$ is always negative since |x| is positive. Would it help to put the e-power then in the denominator (and then the exponent is positive) whereas we have a polynomial term ($a$ is finite) in the numerator?

Comment: Is the first $3$ intended ???

Comment: I have returned the question to its topic, as there are already two detailed answers. If you want to ask about something else, post a separate question.

Comment: @Blue: Indeed.  I saw the question and the posted answers, and I was at a loss to understand what happened.

Answer (score 1):

$$\ln\left[e^{-2b|x|}(1+x^2)^a\right]=-2b|x|+a\ln(1+x^2)$$
It suffices to show that
$$\lim_{|x|\to\infty}\left[-2b|x|+a\ln(1+x^2)\right]=-\infty$$
Now we have
$$\lim_{|x|\to\infty}\left[-2b|x|+a\ln(1+x^2)\right]=-\lim_{|x|\to\infty}|x|\left[2b-a\frac{\ln(1+x^2)}{|x|}\right]$$
Since
$$\lim_{|x|\to\infty}\left[2b-a\frac{\ln(1+x^2)}{|x|}\right]=2b-\lim_{|x|\to\infty}a\frac{\frac{2x}{1+x^2}}{\pm 1}=2b$$
Hence
$$-\lim_{|x|\to\infty}|x|\left[2b-a\frac{\ln(1+x^2)}{|x|}\right]=-\infty$$

Comment: A new idea : put $|x|=y^2$
$$ \lim_{|x|\to\infty}e^{-2b|x|}(1+x^2)^{a}=
\\ \lim_{|x|\to\infty}\frac{(1+x^2)^{a}}{e^{-2b|x|}}=
\\ \lim_{y\to +\infty}\frac{(1+y^4)^{a}}{e^{-2by}}$$ you can take hopital @ here ...

Comment: How to Cancel this question? @Blue.

Comment: Very complicate proof for such an easy problem...

Answer (score 1):

You're better setting $t=|x|$ and write the limit in a simpler way:
$$
\lim_{t\to\infty}e^{-2bt}(1+t^2)^a=
\lim_{t\to\infty}\bigl(e^{-2bt/a}(1+t^2)\bigr)^a
$$
Since $a>1$ it's sufficient to prove that, for $k>0$,
$$
\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{1+t^2}{e^{2kt}}=0
$$
We can further simplify, by noticing that, for $t>1$,
$$
t^2<1+t^2<2t^2
$$
and so it's sufficient to show
$$
\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{t^2}{e^{2kt}}=
\lim_{t\to\infty}\left(\frac{t}{e^{kt}}\right)^{\!2}=0
$$
and again this is implied if we see that
$$
\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{t}{e^{kt}}=0
$$
Now apply just once l'Hôpital.

Comment: @QuocAnh Since you're interested in the limit for $t\to\infty$, it's not restrictive to assume $t>1$.

Comment: @QuocAnh That's another strategy, but it requires computing two limits instead of one. 

Answer (score 0):

The fact that $e^x>x$ for all $x$ is a common result. Therefore,
$$0\leq e^{-2b|x|}\leq \frac{1}{2b|x|}.$$
Using squeeze theorem, the claim follow.